# Android programatically wait for a window then automatically push button

Tags: android, teamviewer

I will like to remote control an Android TV box with QS TeamViewer.

Installed TeamViewer on a computer and QS TeamViewer on the Android TV box.

Upon connection from computer to Android TV box, there is a popup on the Android TV box that ask for user intervention.

User must click on the Allow button in order to activate the remote control of the Android TV box.

How can I programatically wait for a window on the Android TV box that have the title : "Allow remote support?" and click on the Allow button automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UI automation tool such as Espresso or UiAutomator. There you can programatically wait for window/text and push a button when it appears.